# Linq Orderby vs SQL Orderby

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, linq

I have a table column (Varchar)  with the following data :

***COLUMN_NAME***

1. 102100
2. 1-2000
3. 112100

When I use OrderBy in the SQL statement, I get the items in following order :

***COLUMN_NAME***

1. 1-2000
2. 102100
3. 112100

If I query the data ( data comes from WCF ) and use LINQ OrderBy , I get the Items in following order:

***PropertyName***

1. 102100
2. 112100
3. 1-2000

The data "1-2000" seems to get ordered differently in SQL and LINQ.

I tried using `StringComparison.Ordinal` and `StringComparison.InvariantCulture`, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Kindly help!

Comment: Could you share your code example? StringComparer.Ordinal should give the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the linq sort method with the ordinal StringComparer

```
list.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

This gives me your expected result.

Answer (score 5):

As your question is tagged as "Oracle", I guess that you are sending SQL statements to an Oracle database.

The sorting used by an Oracle database is defined in the "NLS" settings. The default value of this setting depends on how Oracle has been installed and the operating system on the host server.

More information here :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch5lingsort.htm

And a very detailed white paper from Oracle :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/globalization/twp-appdev-linguistic-sorting-10gr2-132064.pdf

Extract :

"Spain traditionally treats *ch*, *ll* as well as *ñ* as letters of their own, ordered after *c*, *l* and *n* respectively. For example, the following Spanish words would be sorted as listed:

cabalmente, caba**ll**a, cantina, ca**ñ**a, clamar, curador, **ch**ácara

Recently, this traditional Spanish sorting practice has been replaced with the modern Spanish sort, which removes the special status of *ch* and *ll*."

Comment: Thanks for the great info.